# How to get the domain name from host file  in java?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have the below code snippet in a JSP file. In this code snippet, I am forming the URL  with the IP address. Instead of the IP address, I want the domain name. (Here, the domain name, I mean the entry I have defined for localhost in the host file. If it is not defined, it should return probably the machine name. That's what I think it should be)

```
  String ip = "";
  InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
  appUrl=<%=(new java.net.URL(request.getScheme(),ip,request.getServerPort(), "")).toString() %>
```

i tried these options

```
  inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
  inetAddress.getHostName();
```

But both return computer name. How should I get the domain name?

**EDIT** to clarify more  on this 
i have declared the entry i.e 127.0.0.1 myProjectApp in hosts file. 
So in this scenario i want to form the url like http://myProjectApp/ but if i dont decalre it
it should return the machine name like http://machineName/  . The intention behind it is i am sending this url to another machine say B on network . Using this URL machine B will the back connection to A. Hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get a domain/hostname, but they identify different things. One identifies the URL used by the client, and the other identifies the name of the Servlet as defined in the deployment descriptor.

**Retrieve the domain used by the client:**

```
int port = request.getServerPort();

// if port is default or 0, just use the default port.
String appUrl = 
    request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();

// if it's not the default port, append the port to your url
if(port != 80 || port != 443 || port != 0) {
    appUrl += ":" + new Integer(port).toString();
}
```

**Retrieve the host used by the Servlet:**:

```
String servletContextName = request.getServletContext().getServletContextName();
```

See [ServletContext.getServletContextName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName):

> public java.lang.String getServletContextName()
>
> > Returns the name of this web application correponding to this ServletContext as specified in the deployment descriptor for this web application by the display-name element.
> >
> > Returns:
> >     The name of the web application or null if no name has been declared in the deployment descriptor.
> >
> > Since:
> >     Servlet 2.3

Comment: But request.getServerName() always return localhost though i have declared the entry i.e 127.0.0.1     myProjectApp in hosts file. So in this scenario i expect it should return myProjectApp?

Comment: If you're trying to read information related to your configuration, consider using Environment variables. You might also want to update your question to include the framework you're using and more code examples. In your question, you asked to get the URL instead of IP address, and without the detail, I assumed you meant domain name as in the domain name the user types in the browser.

Comment: Are you looking for the Servlet Context Name?  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName()